# Как запустить пайтон файл без консоли?

Tags: python

Пишу небольшую прогу и столкнулся с проблемой запуска отдельного python файла без консольной оболочки.
Необходимо что бы файл просто запустился без консольной оболочки, выполнил заложенный в него код и закрылся.
Слышал что данную проблему возможно решить при помощи ShellExecute() но каким образом это возможно сделать точно я не знаю.
P.S. про метод с изменением расширения с .py на .pyw я в курсе однако он мне не совсем подходит.

Comment: "не совсем" - это как? Вообще, запускается не файл, а интерпретатор с путем к файлу, переданным через параметр. Под windows можно запускать с помощью pythonw.exe вместо python.exe, тогда консоль не будет открываться (с помощью pythonw.exe запускаются файлы с расширением pyw).

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Хотелось бы еще спросить возможно ли запустить без консоли python файл перекомпилированый с помощью pyinstaller в .exe формат

Comment: Можно, для этого есть соответствующий ключ командной строки в pyinstaller.

Comment: вот посмотри, может поможет https://pypi.org/project/python-daemon/